# Go through json line by line including unkown nested arrays and objects

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a JSON dictionary that can be composed of unknown objects and arrays, but I know which keys I need to modify.

My code will go through the JSON file and if it has certain keys say, 'Date' it will perform other tasks.

The code works for the outer keys, but if there is a nested key with the name 'Date', it is being skipped.

I need the code to go through all the keys, line by line.

Code below.

```
def Converttimestamp(x):
    format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'

    print(x)

    for e in x:
        print(e)
        for column in ['JournalDate','CreatedDateUTC','UpdatedDateUTC','Date','DueDate','DeliveryDate','ExpectedArrivalDate','DateUTC']:
                if column in e:

                    ts = e[column]
                    print ("\n" + str(ts) + "\n")

                    ts_utc = re.split('\(|\)', ts)[1]
                    ts_utc = ts_utc[:ts_utc.find("+")]

                    e[column] = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts_utc)/1000).strftime(format)
                    print(str(e[column]))
    return(e)
```

JSON Dictonary:

```
  x = {
        "InvoiceID": "8930",
        "InvoiceNumber": "Inv. 1",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [
            {
                "PaymentID": "538",
                "Date": "/Date(1406246400000+0000)/",
                "Amount": 118.0,
                "Reference": "",
                "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
                "HasAccount": false,
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            }
        ],
        "AmountDue": 0.0,
        "AmountPaid": 118.0,
        "AmountCredited": 0.0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
        "Date": "/Date(1406246400000+0000)/",
        "DueDate": "/Date(1406246400000+0000)/"
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1406246400000+0000)/"
    }
```

Result JSON Dictionary:

```
      {
        "InvoiceID": "8930",
        "InvoiceNumber": "Inv. 1",
        "Reference": "",
        "Payments": [
            {
                "PaymentID": "538",
                "Date": "/Date(1406246400000+0000)/",
                "Amount": 118.0,
                "Reference": "",
                "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
                "HasAccount": false,
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            }
        ],
        "AmountDue": 0.0,
        "AmountPaid": 118.0,
        "AmountCredited": 0.0,
        "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
        "Date": "2014-06-30T02:00:00.000000",
        "DueDate": "2014-06-30T02:00:00.000000"
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "2014-12-15T14:08:51.843000"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Dates` is inside a `list` inside of the `Payments` key therefore it must be extracted by accessing the dictionary inside the list.

### Data

```py
data = [{'AmountCredited': 0.0,
         'AmountDue': 0.0,
         'AmountPaid': 118.0,
         'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
         'Date': '/Date(1206246400000+0000)/',
         'DueDate': '/Date(1306246400000+0000)/',
         'InvoiceID': '8930',
         'InvoiceNumber': 'Inv. 1',
         'Payments': [{'Amount': 118.0,
                       'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                       'Date': '/Date(1406246400000+0000)/',
                       'HasAccount': False,
                       'HasValidationErrors': False,
                       'PaymentID': '538',
                       'Reference': '',
                       'TestDate': 'failtest in'},
                      {'Amount': 118.0,
                       'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                       'Date': '/Date(1506246400000+0000)/',
                       'HasAccount': False,
                       'HasValidationErrors': False,
                       'PaymentID': '538',
                       'Reference': '',
                       'TestDate': 'failtest in in'}],
         'Reference': '',
         'TestDate': 'failtest out',
         'UpdatedDateUTC': '/Date(1606246400000+0000)/'},
        {'AmountCredited': 0.0,
         'AmountDue': 0.0,
         'AmountPaid': 118.0,
         'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
         'Date': '/Date(1206246400000+0000)/',
         'DueDate': '/Date(1306246400000+0000)/',
         'InvoiceID': '8930',
         'InvoiceNumber': 'Inv. 1',
         'Payments': [{'Amount': 118.0,
                       'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                       'Date': '/Date(1406246400000+0000)/',
                       'HasAccount': False,
                       'HasValidationErrors': False,
                       'PaymentID': '538',
                       'Reference': '',
                       'TestDate': 'failtest in'},
                      {'Amount': 118.0,
                       'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                       'Date': '/Date(1506246400000+0000)/',
                       'HasAccount': False,
                       'HasValidationErrors': False,
                       'PaymentID': '538',
                       'Reference': '',
                       'TestDate': 'failtest in in'}],
         'Reference': '',
         'TestDate': 'failtest out',
         'UpdatedDateUTC': '/Date(1606246400000+0000)/'}]
```

### Code

```py
from datetime import datetime

def to_iso(ts):
    format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
    try:
        ts_utc = re.findall('\d+', ts)[0]
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts_utc)/1000).strftime(format)
    except (IndexError, TypeError):
        print(f'A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: {ts}')
        return ts


def convert_timestamp(my_list_of_dicts: list):

    for e in my_list_of_dicts:
        # check top level keys whose values are not a list
        keys_with_date = [k for k, v in e.items() if 'Date' in k and type(v) != list]

        for k1 in keys_with_date:
            e[k1] = to_iso(e[k1])


        # check top level keys whose values are a list
        keys_with_lists = [k for k, v in e.items() if type(v) == list]

        for k1 in keys_with_lists:
            for i, d in enumerate(e[k1]):
                for k2, v in d.items():
                    if 'Date' in k2:
                        e[k1][i][k2] = to_iso(d[k2])

    return my_list_of_dicts
```

### Usage and output

```py
test = convert_timestamp(data)

A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: failtest out
A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: failtest in
A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: failtest in in
A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: failtest out
A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: failtest in
A key with "Date", but failed to convert the value: failtest in in

print(test)

[{'AmountCredited': 0.0,
  'AmountDue': 0.0,
  'AmountPaid': 118.0,
  'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
  'Date': '2008-03-22T21:26:40.000000',
  'DueDate': '2011-05-24T07:13:20.000000',
  'InvoiceID': '8930',
  'InvoiceNumber': 'Inv. 1',
  'Payments': [{'Amount': 118.0,
                'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                'Date': '2014-07-24T17:00:00.000000',
                'HasAccount': False,
                'HasValidationErrors': False,
                'PaymentID': '538',
                'Reference': '',
                'TestDate': 'failtest in'},
               {'Amount': 118.0,
                'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                'Date': '2017-09-24T02:46:40.000000',
                'HasAccount': False,
                'HasValidationErrors': False,
                'PaymentID': '538',
                'Reference': '',
                'TestDate': 'failtest in in'}],
  'Reference': '',
  'TestDate': 'failtest out',
  'UpdatedDateUTC': '2020-11-24T11:33:20.000000'},
 {'AmountCredited': 0.0,
  'AmountDue': 0.0,
  'AmountPaid': 118.0,
  'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
  'Date': '2008-03-22T21:26:40.000000',
  'DueDate': '2011-05-24T07:13:20.000000',
  'InvoiceID': '8930',
  'InvoiceNumber': 'Inv. 1',
  'Payments': [{'Amount': 118.0,
                'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                'Date': '2014-07-24T17:00:00.000000',
                'HasAccount': False,
                'HasValidationErrors': False,
                'PaymentID': '538',
                'Reference': '',
                'TestDate': 'failtest in'},
               {'Amount': 118.0,
                'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
                'Date': '2017-09-24T02:46:40.000000',
                'HasAccount': False,
                'HasValidationErrors': False,
                'PaymentID': '538',
                'Reference': '',
                'TestDate': 'failtest in in'}],
  'Reference': '',
  'TestDate': 'failtest out',
  'UpdatedDateUTC': '2020-11-24T11:33:20.000000'}]
```

Comment: @user2520212 I would make a new question and be sure to include a complete example of the dictionary. Send a note when it's posted please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419115/search-for-key-inside-list-inside-inside-nested-dictionaries