# Search for key inside nested lists inside nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json

The original post is [Go through json line by line including unkown nested arrays and objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312685/go-through-json-line-by-line-including-unkown-nested-arrays-and-objects)

I am trying to search for a specific value in all nested lists and nested dictionaries inside a JSON dictionary. The structure of the dictionary is not always known. The nested dictionary can have a nested list.

The key I'm looking for is **Date** and should not have **String**. Example key = **Date** is **True** but if key = **DateString** condition is not met.

## **Code:**

```
def ConvertTimestamp(my_list_of_dicts: list):

        for e in my_list_of_dicts:
            # check top level keys whose values are not a list
            keys_with_date = [k for k, v in e.items() if 'Date' in k and type(v) and 'String' not in k != list]

            for k1 in keys_with_date:
                e[k1] = 'found'


            # check top level keys whose values are a list
            keys_with_lists = [k for k, v in e.items() if type(v) == list]

            for k1 in keys_with_lists:
                for i, d in enumerate(e[k1]):
                    for k2, v in d.items():
                        if 'Date' in k2 and 'String' not in k2:
                            e[k1][i][k2] = 'found'

        return my_list_of_dicts
```

## **Data**

```
test_data = [{
            "PurchaseOrderID": "aaff50c2-05d5-4943-9a37-421d1b326dc3",
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "PO-0001",
            "DateString": "2020-06-04T00:00:00",
            "Date": "2020-06-04T02:00:00.000000",
            "DeliveryDateString": "2020-06-11T00:00:00",
            "DeliveryDate": "2020-06-11T02:00:00.000000",
            "DeliveryAddress": "",
            "AttentionTo": "",
            "Telephone": "",
            "DeliveryInstructions": "",
            "HasErrors": false,
            "IsDiscounted": true,
            "Reference": "",
            "Type": "PURCHASEORDER",
            "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
            "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "31dcd998-026662967",
                "ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "Name": "Test",
                "FirstName": "",
                "LastName": "",
                "Addresses": [],
                "Phones": [],
                "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1591272554130+0000)/",
                "ContactGroups": [],
                "DefaultCurrency": "EUR",
                "ContactPersons": [],
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            },
            "BrandingThemeID": "86a1c878-7b2ed792b224",
            "Status": "DELETED",
            "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
            "SubTotal": 1000.0,
            "TotalTax": 0.0,
            "Total": 1000.0,
            "UpdatedDateUTC": "2020-06-04T12:14:26.527000",
            "HasAttachments": false }]
```

## **Result should be**

```
[{
            "PurchaseOrderID": "aaff50c2-05d5-4943-9a37-421d1b326dc3",
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "PO-0001",
            "DateString": "2020-06-04T00:00:00",
            "Date": "2020-06-04T02:00:00.000000",
            "DeliveryDateString": "2020-06-11T00:00:00",
            "DeliveryDate": "2020-06-11T02:00:00.000000",
            "DeliveryAddress": "",
            "AttentionTo": "",
            "Telephone": "",
            "DeliveryInstructions": "",
            "HasErrors": false,
            "IsDiscounted": true,
            "Reference": "",
            "Type": "PURCHASEORDER",
            "CurrencyRate": 1.0,
            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
            "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "31dcd998-026662967",
                "ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "Name": "Test",
                "FirstName": "",
                "LastName": "",
                "Addresses": [],
                "Phones": [],
                "UpdatedDateUTC": "2020-06-03T09:55:30.000000",
                "ContactGroups": [],
                "DefaultCurrency": "EUR",
                "ContactPersons": [],
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            },
            "BrandingThemeID": "86a1c878-7b2ed792b224",
            "Status": "DELETED",
            "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
            "SubTotal": 1000.0,
            "TotalTax": 0.0,
            "Total": 1000.0,
            "UpdatedDateUTC": "2020-06-04T12:14:26.527000",
            "HasAttachments": false }]
```

Comment: What exactly should it return in this example?

Comment: added result to thread

Comment: if you have nested data then you could use "nested" function - it means recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what the structure of the dictionaries are, it could be under an arbitrary number of levels.

Also, the expected result didn't really show what you want to do with the dictionary once found, so I've just added those dictionaries to a list.

Recursion helps in such cases.

```
def search_dict(d, results):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if 'Date' in k and 'String' not in k:
            # Do what you want with `d` here.
            # Your "Result should be" didn't really explain the
            # found part, but if it gets here it means you found it.

            # Appended to results as we want to continue searching for more.
            # Appending (k,v,d) where d is the dictionary containing
            # this key and value, incase you wanted that too. 
            # Adjust this accordingly.
            results.append((k,v,d))

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            search_dict(v, results)

        if isinstance(v, list):
            search_list(v, results)

def search_list(l, results):
    for item in l:
        if not isinstance(item, dict):
            continue # don't care about things that aren't dictionaries

        if isinstance(item, list):
            search_list(item, results)

        if isinstance(item, dict):
            search_dict(item, results)

def ConvertTimestamp(my_list_of_dicts: list):
    results = []
    search_list(my_list_of_dicts, results)
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can recurse through the object, making the updates.

For sake of generality, the recursive function takes two externally defined callables an addition to the object being recursed:

- a "key tester" function that should take a key (string) and return a boolean, which is used to decide which keys are to have their values updated
- a "replacer" function that should take a value and return the new value

```
from datetime import date
from pprint import pprint
from copy import deepcopy
import re


def do_replacements(obj, key_tester, replacer):
    """
    recursing through the nested list/dict structure,
    and wherever key_tester(key) yields True, 
    use replacer function to generate the new value
    """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if key_tester(k):
                obj[k] = replacer(v)
            else:
                do_replacements(v, key_tester, replacer)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            do_replacements(item, key_tester, replacer)


def fix_time(ts):
    """
    replace the timestamp if it fits a particular pattern
    (based on code in original question)
    """
    pattern = '\(|\)'
    if not re.search(pattern, ts):
        return ts
    format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
    ts_utc = re.split(pattern, ts)[1]
    ts_utc = ts_utc[:ts_utc.find("+")]
    return date.fromtimestamp(float(ts_utc)/1000).strftime(format)


test_data =    [{'PurchaseOrderID': 'aaff50c2-05d5-4943-9a37-421d1b326dc3', 'PurchaseOrderNumber': 'PO-0001', 'DateString': '2020-06-04T00:00:00', 'Date': '2020-06-04T02:00:00.000000', 'DeliveryDateString': '2020-06-11T00:00:00', 'DeliveryDate': '2020-06-11T02:00:00.000000', 'DeliveryAddress': '', 'AttentionTo': '', 'Telephone': '', 'DeliveryInstructions': '', 'HasErrors': False, 'IsDiscounted': True, 'Reference': '', 'Type': 'PURCHASEORDER', 'CurrencyRate': 1.0, 'CurrencyCode': 'EUR', 'Contact': {'ContactID': '31dcd998-026662967', 'ContactStatus': 'ACTIVE', 'Name': 'Test', 'FirstName': '', 'LastName': '', 'Addresses': [], 'Phones': [], 'UpdatedDateUTC': '/Date(1591272554130+0000)/', 'ContactGroups': [], 'DefaultCurrency': 'EUR', 'ContactPersons': [], 'HasValidationErrors': False}, 'BrandingThemeID': '86a1c878-7b2ed792b224', 'Status': 'DELETED', 'LineAmountTypes': 'Exclusive', 'SubTotal': 1000.0, 'TotalTax': 0.0, 'Total': 1000.0, 'UpdatedDateUTC': '2020-06-04T12:14:26.527000', 'HasAttachments': False}]


func = lambda k: "Date" in k and "String" not in k

output = deepcopy(test_data)
do_replacements(output, func, fix_time)
pprint(output)
```

gives:

```
[{'AttentionTo': '',
  'BrandingThemeID': '86a1c878-7b2ed792b224',
  'Contact': {'Addresses': [],
              'ContactGroups': [],
              'ContactID': '31dcd998-026662967',
              'ContactPersons': [],
              'ContactStatus': 'ACTIVE',
              'DefaultCurrency': 'EUR',
              'FirstName': '',
              'HasValidationErrors': False,
              'LastName': '',
              'Name': 'Test',
              'Phones': [],
              'UpdatedDateUTC': '2020-06-04T00:00:00.000000'},
  'CurrencyCode': 'EUR',
  'CurrencyRate': 1.0,
  'Date': '2020-06-04T02:00:00.000000',
  'DateString': '2020-06-04T00:00:00',
  'DeliveryAddress': '',
  'DeliveryDate': '2020-06-11T02:00:00.000000',
  'DeliveryDateString': '2020-06-11T00:00:00',
  'DeliveryInstructions': '',
  'HasAttachments': False,
  'HasErrors': False,
  'IsDiscounted': True,
  'LineAmountTypes': 'Exclusive',
  'PurchaseOrderID': 'aaff50c2-05d5-4943-9a37-421d1b326dc3',
  'PurchaseOrderNumber': 'PO-0001',
  'Reference': '',
  'Status': 'DELETED',
  'SubTotal': 1000.0,
  'Telephone': '',
  'Total': 1000.0,
  'TotalTax': 0.0,
  'Type': 'PURCHASEORDER',
  'UpdatedDateUTC': '2020-06-04T12:14:26.527000'}]
```

(Note: the output shown here is the pretty-printed python object, rather than JSON, although similar.)